# In radio transmission, aren't all forms of modulation ultimately FM?

Tags: wireless, radio, transmission

This is a very basic question, but I am confused by this.

All forms of radio transmission result in sidebands or a frequency range (channel) that is used to carry the data.

Even AM somehow results in frequency modulation, which I don't understand.

FM is the only thing that's actually called frequency modulation, but isn't everything technically FM?

Phase, amplitude and frequency modulation or any combination of them, all result in sidebands (defined as a frequency range), so they are all forms of FM, is that fair to say?

If so, how is *actual* FM different from the rest? And how does AM result in sidebands?

Comment: To answer all your questions requires several chapters of a book so, please refine your question to something that requires less coverage. If you can't do that then maybe you should do some background research on why amplitude modulation causes sidebands (not the same sidebands created by FM). When you have done that please state what level of mathematics you are comfortable with i.e. trig functions, algebra etc..

Comment: *Even AM somehow results in frequency modulation* No it does not. What AM does influence is the **spectrum** of the signal. A 1 kHz AM modulation will result in a (2 kHz: -1 kHz and +1 kHz) wider spectrum. That is not the same as FM.

Comment: You have made a good observation that all modulation forms disrupt the pure sine wave carrier spike seen on the spectrum analyzer. But FM and PM and AM are all well defined and studied and characterized separately in communications textbooks. So you have to use the definition of FM presented in the textbooks if you want to read them and understand them. If you say "It is really all just FM" and then insist on only reading about FM in the text book you will miss out on a lot of other information. It is best to begin your education with some humility.

Answer (score 6):

No, not everything is technically FM, because only in FM the signal modulates the carrier frequency. Only a zero signal will result in carrier being the nominal frequency, as the signal will directly select carrier frequency.

Phase modulation is close to it, but any signal that has constant DC and does not change will result in the nominal carrier frequency, as it will keep the phase constant.

AM simply multiplies a sine wave carrier with the signal.

And yes the resulting waveform will have sidelobes, as only a sine wave that does not change in any way has only one frequency.

Answer (score 2):

> All forms of radio transmission result in sidebands or a frequency range (channel) that is used to carry the data.

Yes

> Even AM somehow results in frequency modulation, which I don't understand.

No, not pure AM. AM sometimes, through a bad transmitter, can generate some 'incidental' FM, which is not needed and is unwanted.

> FM is the only thing that's actually called frequency modulation...

Yes

> ... but isn't everything technically FM?

No

> Phase, amplitude and frequency modulation or any combination of them, all result in sidebands (defined as a frequency range)

sidebands yes, but sidebands have both an amplitude and a phase with respect to the carrier. If you observe them on a spectrum analyser, you lose the phase information and see only the amplitude. However a receiver demodulating the signal demodulates in-phase sidebands as AM, and quadrature sidebands as FM, or more strictly PM

> ... so they are all forms of FM, is that fair to say?

see above, no.

> If so, how is actual FM different from the rest? And how does AM result in sidebands?
>
> Sorry, lots of questions.

One way to break down the modulation on a signal is modulation on the amplitude of the carrier, and modulation on the angle of the carrier.

Amplitude modulation creates one set of sidebands that are in phase with the carrier, and have even symmetry about the carrier.

Phase modulation creates many sets of sidebands with odd symmetry about the carrier, the first set in quadrature with it, the successive sets a further 90 degrees shifted from the previous set (so some sets will be in phase or anti-phase to the carrier).

FM is just the rate of change of PM with time. They are the same physical thing on the signal. FM and PM are just different ways to describe, generate or recover the same modulation.

Often modulation angles below one radian are called PM, and many radians are called FM, but that's not a rule.

When complex modulation is used which *could* be described as AM+PM, it's more likely to be called QAM or some such.

Answer (score 1):

From a practical viewpoint:

One reason why we call AM "AM" is because, If you build a circuit that measures the *amplitude* of a signal that passes through a very narrow band-pass filter centered on the carrier frequency, and you feed that circuit an AM radio signal, then the output will be a pretty good representation of the original modulation. But the same circuit will do a poor job of recovering the modulation from an FM signal. (Google for "slope detection" to learn why it works at all for FM.)

OTOH, we can call FM "FM" because, If you build a phase-locked-loop (PLL) circuit that tracks the *frequency* of a carrier wave, and you feed it an FM signal, then the "error" signal from the PLL will be a pretty good representation of the modulation. But if you feed the same circuit an AM radio signal, then you won't get any output at all.

There's "sidebands" associated with *any* type of modulation, but what would be the point of giving the same name, "FM," to *every* type of modulation? It's much more useful to give different names to the different types--names that tell us something about how the modulator and the de-modulator works.

Answer (score 1):

All types of frequency or phase modulation have on common property: The amplitude of the signal is constant. Obviously that is not the case for amplitude modulation.
But an amplitude modulated carrier never the less must show signal components with frequencies different from the carrier frequency, because a pure carrier (with constant frequency) has a zero bandwidth. And with zero bandwidth no information can be transmitted.
Let's look at a little bit of elementary mathematics. So let us assume the modulation frequency is y and the carrier frequency is x. The amplitudes of both signals are equal. Then the resulting modulated signal s is
s = sin(x) * sin(y) = 0,5 * (cos(x-y) - cos(x + y))
Signal s is the sum of two signals with the sum and the difference of modulation frequency and carrier frequency. These are the AM-typical sidebands. In this example the carrier vanishes completely.
If you replace the modulating signal sin(y) by (1 - a + a * sin(y)) you will see that the carrier does not vanish.
The frequency of the AM sidebands does not depend on the amplitude of the modulating signal but it depends solely on it's frequency, while with frequency modulation and phase modulation the frequency deviation from the carrier frequency depends on the modulating signal amplitude.